# How to write a txt file with the log from the `npm list` command?

Tags: node.js, logging, npm, text-files, fs

`npm list` logs this:

[image]

How can I save that as a `txt` file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Works on newer Windows OS and Linux/Mac:

```
npm list > logs.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! Did not know that.